# componentDidMount does show intermediate state even though React docs suggest otherwise

Tags: reactjs

**1st premise:**

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted (inserted into the tree).

**2nd premise:**

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidMount(). It will trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen before the browser updates the screen. This guarantees that even though the render() will be called twice in this case, the user won’t see the intermediate state.

both from https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

**My conclusion:**

Based on the above, mounting cannot be the last step in displaying to the browser, otherwise what is rendered and mounted (any intermediate state) before `componentDidMount` will always be shown.

---

However, based on my experience, I've found that any state specified in the constructor does in fact get shown before any overriding state changes in `componentDidMount`.

This is suggesting to me that premise 2 is incorrect. My conclusion is therefore incorrect as well. Mounting must be the final step in displaying to the browser.

Can anyone clear this up for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you set the state in componentDidMount synchronously, the new state will be the only one shown (or at least the switch would happen so fast after rendering it would be impossible to detect).

If you're trying to set it asynchronously, such as using results from a fetch, then you would see the initial state until the async call is completed.

Comment: Thanks. I had a hunch of the same after posting. Gah, I guess the docs were assuming a synchronous world and I should have realized that faster.